# how to make a valid request?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day.

Query select distinct rows from table in database:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
f.id_service as f_id_service,
 f.id_city as f_id_city, 
f.name as f_name, 
f.address as f_address, 
f.business as f_business, 
f.web as f_web, 
f.phone as f_phone, 
f.id_firm as f_id_firm, 
p.name as p_name 
FROM Firm f left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm
```

for navigation i use NOT IN:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT TOP 20 
f.id_service as f_id_service,
 f.id_city as f_id_city, 
f.name as f_name, 
f.address as f_address, 
f.business as f_business, 
f.web as f_web, 
f.phone as f_phone, 
f.id_firm as f_id_firm, 
p.name as p_name 
FROM Firm f left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm 

WHERE 

f.name 
NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 
f.name FROM Firm f 
left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm 
WHERE p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0' AND f.blocked='0' AND p.id_group='44' AND p.id_subgroup='266' 
ORDER BY f.name ASC
) 
AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm AND p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0' 
AND f.blocked='0' AND p.id_group='44' AND p.id_subgroup='266'
ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

In last query was check `f.name NOT IN` but I need to check the entire string as in the first query, not only `f.name`.

how make this?

Comment: where f.id_firm NOT in (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 f.id_firm FROM Firm f ) ?

Comment: Take a look at NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FIRM ...... WHERE etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT f.name as f_name, 
max(f.address) as f_address, 
max(f.business) as f_business, 
max(f.web) as f_web, 
max(f.phone) as f_phone, 
max(p.name) as p_name 
FROM Firm f 
left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service 
AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm

WHERE 

f.name NOT IN (
SELECT TOP $numnext 
f.name 
FROM Firm f 
left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service AND p.id_city=f.id_city 
AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm
WHERE 
p.id_firm=f.id_firm AND p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0' 
AND f.blocked='0' AND p.id_group='44' AND p.id_subgroup='266' 
GROUP BY f.name
ORDER BY f.name ASC
) 

AND
p.id_firm=f.id_firm AND p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0'
AND f.blocked='0' AND p.id_group='44' AND p.id_subgroup='266'
GROUP BY f.name
ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
          f_id_service = f.id_service
        , f_id_city = f.id_city
        , f_name = f.name
        , f_address = f.[address]
        , f_business = f.business
        , f_web = f.web
        , f_phone = f.phone
        , f_id_firm = f.id_firm
        , p_name = p.name
    FROM Firm f
    LEFT JOIN Price p ON p.id_service = f.id_service AND p.id_city = f.id_city AND p.id_firm = f.id_firm
    WHERE p.id_city = '73041' 
        AND p.[include] = '1' 
        AND p.blocked = '0' 
        AND f.blocked = '0' 
        AND p.id_group = '44' 
        AND p.id_subgroup = '266'
)
SELECT TOP 20   
      f_id_service
    , f_id_city
    , f_name
    , f_address
    , f_business
    , f_web
    , f_phone
    , f_id_firm
    , p_name
FROM cte
WHERE f_name NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 f_name
        FROM cte
        ORDER BY f_name
    )
ORDER BY f_name
```

Comment: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Invalid column name 'f_id_service'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'f_id_city'.`